# Splitting Hexadecimal Strings: return the minimum number of splits such that each split is a hexadecimal representation of a perfect square

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

How would you guys approach this? I got this question in an interview.

Example: 896bb1 returns 1 because it is the hexadecimal representation of 9006001, which is a perfect square of 3001. Example: 1a919 returns 3 because 1, a9, and 19 are hexadecimal representations of perfect squares, and 3 is the minimum number of splits required.

Comment: The perfect squares and the hexadecimal representation are red herrings. You can generate by rule a list of the possible substrings up to any desired length. It doesn’t matter what the rule is! Now it’s just a question of looking for those substrings in your target string.

Comment: With a number like 1a919, there are only 4 possible split points, so there are only 16 possibilities to try. You could just try them all.

Comment: 1. generate all hex strings of perfect squares up to the input limit. 2. use KMP to mark positions where they exist in given string 3. use dynamic programming to compute minimum number of splits
Of course if input is small enough brute-forcing all possible splits is easier

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to this problem in Ruby.

```
MAX_NUM = 999999.freeze

def get_min(hex)
  return "Invalid hex" unless validate_hex?(hex)

  pieces = min_breaks(hex)
  return -1 if pieces == MAX_NUM

  pieces
end

def min_breaks(hex, index = 0)
  hex_length = hex.length
  return 0 if index == hex_length

  numeric = 0
  result = MAX_NUM

  for i in index..hex_length-1 do
    numeric = numeric * 16 + hex[i].hex
    result = [result, 1 + min_breaks(hex, i + 1)].min if is_square?(numeric)
  end

  result
end

def is_square?(x)
  (Math.sqrt(x) % 1).zero?
end

def validate_hex?(hex)
  hex =~ /^[0-9a-f]+$/i
end

puts "Enter hex string:"
hex = gets.chomp

puts "Output: #{get_min(hex.downcase)}"
```